# Iphone load image into webview from documentsDirectory

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to download, save and show again an image. I'v manage to downolad it and store it to documents directory. So now if i go there with finder i can see those images. Now i'm trying to load it into web view. For that i use these code:

```
[webview loadHTMLString:simpleHtml baseURL:nil];
```

In my simple html i have:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<img src='/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/45584ECD-021A-4789-8936-6A0012242380/Documents/image.png' />
</body></html>
```

It loads but it shows a question mark, like if there were no image at that directory.(The image is there because i can find it in finder...)

btw simpleHtml is a NSString not folder...

Comment: Did you hardcode the source path of the image in `simpleHtml`?

Comment: No i get it from NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"image.png"]; And then i append it to nsmutable string

Comment: why don't you directly take the NSURL of image and show it in webview?

Comment: because i want to save it for later when user maybe wont have internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally get it to work, however it dons't work with html. I use image data now.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:image];
[webview loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```

Now i find out another solution even better: To my original html string i need to ad prefix file:. So i have now:

```
<img src="file:/path">
```

And it works like a charm!

Comment: can u please ealborate what are file and path for src?

Answer (score 2):

you can check this it will be help you.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

You can then refer to your images like this:

or you can refer this link:

http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited

Comment: my path is now /Users/mitjaresek/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/45584ECD-021A-4789-8936-6A0012242380/ZM.app  but that doesnt help i steal get no image :S

Comment: @gabrjan you are use htmlString like this plz check it [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<img src=\"@\" />", [self urlForFileNamed: @"foo" ofType: @"png"]];

Comment: @gabrjan it means when ur pass "htmlstring" at [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
like [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<img src=\"@\" />", [self urlForFileNamed: @"foo" ofType: @"png"]]; this way...

Comment: @gabrjan you can also see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543533/how-to-load-local-images-in-webview-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: well when i call [self urlForFileNamed: @"image" ofType: @"png"]; i don't get anything back ...

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *ImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourimage.png"];
```

Use the above "ImagePath" in your html string.Instead of using 'loadHTMLString' use the following method of webview

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath]]];
```

Comment: NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"image.png"]; i use these and it looks totaly correct. The path i mean.

Comment: check if that image exists at that path

Comment: did u read my question? i wrote that i can find my iamge at that path in finder.